# Struggled with some unknown css-overriding issues by "inline"

Tags: jquery, html, css, openlayers, popover

I have recently a css-overriding problem with kind of "unknown" reason.

The background:

I have constructed a website which contains a table with three columns and in the middle column is a map constructed with help of openlayers, the other columns just show some Infos to the map/layers.

The Problem:

I have all the css under control until I set a popover with jQuery to show some map informations. The popover it self works well but at the moment the popover-window shows, all the css-styles for the whole table change without a reason (e.g. font-size for the table, text-aglin, etc.).

When I check which document has overridden my css, it shows the html tag "tbody" would be changed by "inline" like the picture below:

[image: tbody changed by "inline"and can't be overridden]

But I don't even have a tbody Tag in my html, which i am sure and I also don't write any inline style css which may could have been the reason.

The original codes are too long to post hier so I just want to ask:

1. In the picture, I tried to override the font-size by give the  tag a class, the debug-tool shows that my css style has the first priority but the font-size is still 11.2px not what I defined 14 px. How is that possible?
2. Even I don't have a tbody tag in my html. The tbody tag will be styled by "Inline", what is Inline here actually (If I click the "inline", it shows me ol.css and it contains no usefull information) and how is the possible?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Or is that isn't possible, a link to the website itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of misunderstanding here, which I'll try to clarify.

1. Every `<table>` these days has a `<tbody>`, even if you don't specify it yourself. Meaning that `<table><tr>...</tr></table>` becomes `<table><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>` in the browser.
2. The `tbody` `font-size` style is an **inline** style, meaning that something like `tbody { font-size: 80% }` was declared not in a .css file but **in the page itself**; either in a `<style></style>` block or by using `<tbody style="font-size: 80%">` (but you said that `<tbody>` does not occur on the page).

Comment: Let me explain a little bit. I cheked that I have absolute no inline css in my html, so that is why I am wondering where this inline style comes from. (the <tbody style="font-size: 80%"> never appears in my html)

Comment: I somehow begin to think, as @Tim Gerhard mentioned, if Openlayers (and Bootstraps) has some effect on this problem, but the debug-tool does not show it comes from Bootstrap. I am now confused how to find out where this style comes from.

Comment: Did you check using *View Source* in the browser or by using the browser *Developer Tools*? Stuff might get added or modified at runtime by scripts that run.

Comment: Allthough you're right Peter, as long as he did not write css inline himself the only other way it could be displayed as inline is by a javascript or jquery script.

Comment: @Peter B Yes, the picture I got was from the view Source of Fire Fox Developer Tools. But it helps only a little and to let me know the styles are somehow overridden.